# how to display result in view part in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

```
 public function outofstock(){
     $this->loadModel('Store');
     $store=$this->Store->find('all',array('fields' => array('Store.store_shortcode')));

      $this->set('store',$store);
    foreach($store as $store):
     $store_shortcode= $store['Store']['store_shortcode'];
     $item=$this->Item->find('all',array('conditions' => array($store_shortcode.' =' => 0 )));

     foreach($item as $item1){ 
      echo $item1['Item']['item_name'];
      echo $store_shortcode;
      }
    endforeach;
     $this->set('item',$item);

 }
```

This is my controller part code . 
I want to display echo $item1['Item']['item_name'] , $store_shortcode in view part . Actually in controller its displaying properly but in view part its not displaying . store_shortcode is GLF,DLLK,MKL . Item Name is ADASHG , GRAFGHJ, Store names or columns of item table and store_name of store table .

Comment: please you use the concept of hasMany

Comment: Seriously, why are you tagging this questions with *four* different versions...?

Answer (score 0):

Controller **($items[ ])**:

```
 public function outofstock(){
 $this->loadModel('Store');
 $store=$this->Store->find('all',array('fields' => array('Store.store_shortcode')));

  $this->set('store',$store);
foreach($store as $store):
 $store_shortcode= $store['Store']['store_shortcode'];
 $items[] =$this->Item->find('all',array('conditions' => array($store_shortcode.' =' => 0 )));


endforeach;
 $this->set('items',$items);

}
```

In the view.ctp:

```
foreach($items as $item){ 
  echo $item['Item']['item_name'];
  }
```

**But generally you have a a bad approach,**

Do hasMany relational between the Store and Item model, and then easily with the help of a one query take data.

Comment: I want to display which column having 0 value .. means i want to display $store_shortcode and also $item['Item']['item_name']  in view part

Answer (score 0):

Use this in view file

```
foreach($store as $store):
 $store_shortcode= $store['Store']['store_shortcode'];
 $item=$this->Item->find('all',array('conditions' => array($store_shortcode.' =' => 0 )));
foreach($item as $item1){ 
  echo $item1['Item']['item_name'];
  echo $store_shortcode;
  }
endforeach;
```